# How to rerun scripts on route change React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So in my html head of my React project I've got some scripts like this:

```
<head>
...
<script src="SomeJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
</head>
```

It works fine when loading the page directly or refreshing the page, however I need those scripts to run again when I transition to another route. Since it's not the entire page being reloaded, only a certain component, the scripts won't rerun which causes problems.

How can I force these scripts to run again?

Answer (score 1):

In the script:

```
<script>
  window.someMethod = function() {
    // do something here
  };

  window.someMethod();
</script>
```

In React:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

/// ...

const someMethod = window.someMethod;

class App extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  // ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.onRouteChanged();
    }
  }

  onRouteChanged() {
    someMethod();
  }

  // ...
  render(){
    return <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        // ...
        // ...
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```